# Android Application - Center Title

Tags: java, android

I am currently trying to center my Title in a new Android application. This is the basic title (top of the screen) that android has assigned to the app. The application is a very simple cookie-cutter "Tabbed" application created in Android Studio using the "Tabbed" template.

The title is simple text (about 30 characters). The title shows up in the main.xml when I select the "Design" option, but it is impossible for me to edit. Any help is appreciated.

Below is a copy of my main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.my.app.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Isn't this code your menu.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom `ToolBar` as shown below

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >


 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your Title"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

You can set text of the `TextView` like below

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
tv.setText("Your Text");
```

Comment: Thank You for the help! You still need to turn the default title off, but this is what I needed  to fix my code   :)

Comment: add this line of code to hide it `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTitle("my title") in activity. However there is no method to set it in center as it's not recommendend. But if you still want it then you can just pad with spaces. Like ("                my title")

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with the code, I figured out how to center the Toolbar Title & change the Toolbar Title text.

1st you have to edit the "onCreate" for the activity to turn off the default title provide by android. See sample below:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

2nd you have to delete any references in the Toolbar XML (app:title = "your title" )for the app title. A TextView will then need to be added to the Toolbar XML. Below is a sample of the code that is working for me:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#67ccb2"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:text="MY APP NAME"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Notice in the TextView above that I have recreated the title, changed its text size, made it bold & centered it in the middle (where it looks awesome).

I hope this helps someone  :)